# File link to Outlook item on shared drive

Tags: html, outlook, shared-drive

I'm a technical writer for my company, and we've been tasked with doing an internal knowledge database. I'm trying to take it to the next level and am absolutely stumped with this problem:

I am trying to create links to a shared drive through a CMS (a HTML driven tool). These links are to email templates (.msg) that I want to open with Outlook when the user clicks on them.

I test the files by previewing them on Google Chrome.

However, clicking on the link does nothing. If I click 'Copy link address' and paste into the browser search bar it'll download the file - so the link is fine. But why won't it open with outlook?

The code is basically (I can't reproduce it for company reasons):

```
Click <a href="file://X:/Mainfolder/subfolder/email_template.msg">here</a>.
```